# Sticky navbar position front of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i followed a stackoverflow question to do the first part of the sticky navbar, here is the jFiddle of what i pretend to do [sticky navbar](http://jsfiddle.net/yeco/4EcFf/), i have the menu and the i put all my content in a content class div, the only problem that i have is when i scrool on the page the sticky navbar goes behind the content, i want the sticky navbar to place in front, i tryied it with a z-index and a position relative, but then all my inputs(textarea, links) stop working and it kinda makes sense, how can i archieve what i want to do?

**here is my full code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TSIW - Um curso em inovação</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Hairline|Exo|Maven+Pro|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="page.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row backColor"><img alt="TSIW" class="img img-responsive" src="TSIW.jpg"></div>
        <div class="row backColor">
            <div id="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row menu2">
            <div class="centerBlock">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li class="menuItem">
                        <a href="#aluno">Apresentação</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuItem">
                        <a href="#PlanoEstudos">Plano de Estudos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuItem">
                        <a>Notícias</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuItem">
                        <a>Projetos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuItem">
                        <a>Outros</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row spacing2">
                <h3 id="Apresentacao">Apresentação</h3><iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315" id="aluno" name="aluno" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BdyPhLbCPA8" width="900"></iframe>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <p class="aluno" style="background-color:white;padding:4%;border-radius:10px">A licenciatura em Tecnologias e Sistemas de Informação para a Web é um projeto conjunto da Escola Superior de Estudos Industriais e de Gestão (ESEIG) e do Instituto Superior de Engenharia do Porto (ISEP). O curso funciona nas instalações da ESEIG, com docentes da ESEIG e do ISEP, e o grau é atribuído conjuntamente por estas duas Escolas do Instituto Politécnico do Porto. Tem por objetivo formar profissionais capazes de liderarem projetos nos domínios da conceção, desenvolvimento e gestão de sistemas de informação e de conteúdos para a Web. O Curso privilegia uma sólida formação em design para meios digitais e em tecnologias da informação, procurando formar profissionais que dominem quer a vertente mais criativa do processo produtivo, quer a vertente mais técnica ou tecnológica. O Curso procura privilegiar as tendências emergentes na área das ciências e tecnologias da informação, como a computação centrada na Web (cloud computing), segurança, interfaces gráficas e ambientes virtuais. Os licenciados deverão desenvolver as competências necessárias para se envolverem em projetos de conceção, desenvolvimento e gestão de sistemas de informação e de conteúdos para a Web, suportados nas mais diversas tecnologias e plataformas tecnológicas. O perfil do licenciado compreende as seguintes competências:</p>
                    <p class="foco spacing2">Competências</p>
                    <ul class="spacing4" id="competencias" style="background-color:white;padding-left:4%;border-radius:10px">
                        <li>Conceber, desenvolver e gerir sistemas de informação e produtos para a Web;</li>
                        <li>Demonstrar capacidade de liderança, capacidade de iniciativa e espírito empreendedor;</li>
                        <li>Conceber e desenvolver produtos em ambientes interativos ou 3D;</li>
                        <li>Desenvolver sistemas e produtos para multiplataformas;</li>
                        <li>Projetar e desenvolver produtos digitais de entretenimento e lazer.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="foco spacing2">Saídas Profissionais</p>
                    <ul class="spacing4" id="Saidas" style="background-color:white;padding-left:4%;border-radius:10px">
                        <li>Conceção, desenvolvimento e gestão de software e produtos para a Web;</li>
                        <li>Desenvolvimento de produtos para dispositivos móveis;</li>
                        <li>Conceção e desenvolvimento de software de entretenimento e jogos;</li>
                        <li>Consultadoria na área de sistemas de produtos para a Web</li>
                        <li>Desenvolvimento de plataformas de negócio electrónico;</li>
                        <li>Designer Web.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row spacing2">
                <h3 id="PlanoEstudos">Plano de Estudos</h3>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" style="background-color:white;padding:2%;border-radius:10px">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ano1">1ºano</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ano2">2ºano</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ano3">3ºano</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <table class="table tab-pane fade in active" id="ano1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Unidade Curricular</th>
                                    <th>Tipologia</th>
                                    <th>ECTS</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>MatemáticaI</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Algoritmia e Estrutura de dados</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sistemas Computacionais</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tecnologias e aplicações web</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fundamentos de design</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>MatemáticaII</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Conceção e produção multimédia</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Programação orientada a objetos</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Design Gráfico</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>ProjetoI</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table tab-pane fade" id="ano2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Unidade Curricular</th>
                                    <th>Tipologia</th>
                                    <th>ECTS</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Análise e modelação de sistemas</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Bases de dados</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Física aplicada à programação</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Programação webI</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Animação gráfica</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Engenharia de software</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Modelação e ambientes 3D</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Programação webII</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sistemas gráficos</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>ProjetoII</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table tab-pane fade" id="ano3">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Unidade Curricular</th>
                                    <th>Tipologia</th>
                                    <th>ECTS</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sistemas cistribuidos</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Ergonomia cognitiva e design de interação</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Desenvolvimento de jogos</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Negócio eletrónico e segurança</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Gestão empresarial</td>
                                    <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Técnicas avançadas de web design</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Inovação e empreendedorismo</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Programação para dispositivos móveis</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Projeto final/estágio</td>
                                    <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                                    <td>20</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row spacing2">
                <h3 id="Noticias">Notícias</h3>
                <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="text-carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="carousel-content" style="background-color:white;padding:5%;border-radius:10px">
                                        <div>
                                            <h4 style="text-align:right;font-weight:900">Seminário Gestão de Projectos de Software</h4>
                                            <p style="text-align:right"><b>Orador</b>: Nelson Faria</p><br>
                                            <ul id="noti">
                                                <li>Professional Services Director at Nonius - Hospitality Technology</li>
                                                <li>Professional Services Director</li>
                                                <li>Systems Engineer</li>
                                                <li>Software Enginner</li>
                                            </ul><br>
                                            <p>As inscrições são gratuítas mas obrigatórias para <a href="#">mariopinto@eseig.ipp.pt</a></p>
                                            <p>Uma organização da Licenciatura em TSIW.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="carousel-content" style="background-color:white;padding:5%;border-radius:10px">
                                        <div>
                                            <h4 style="text-align:center;font-weight:900">Seminário de controlo de versões de software</h4>
                                            <p style="text-align:right"><b>Orador</b>: Pedro Cunha, Software Engineer @ Multicert</p>
                                            <p>Quem desenvolve software (SW) apercebe-se que nenhuma aplicação está totalmente acabada, há bugs por detetar, algoritmos a melhorar, interfaces a modificar... Atualmente é impensável desenvolver projetos de SW sem ter um sistema que controle tudo o que acontece, desde alterações de código até à própria documentação. Neste seminário, aberto a toda a comunidade da ESEIG, pretende-se introduzir os conceitos gerais dos sistemas de controlo de versões de SW mais utilizados atualmente, tendo como "case study" o Git.</p><br>
                                            <br>
                                            <p style="text-align:left"><b>Data</b>:Sexta-feira, 20 de maio de 2016, pelas 14h</p>
                                            <p style="text-align:left"><b>Local</b>:Anfiteatro Joaquim Ribeiro (B101), ESEIG</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="carousel-content" style="background-color:white;padding:5%;border-radius:10px">
                                        <div>
                                            <h4 style="text-align:center;font-weight:900">Desenvolvimento de Jogos em Unity em 120 minutos</h4>
                                            <p style="text-align:right"><b>Orador</b>: Alberto Simões, IPCA.</p>
                                            <p>Neste seminário procura-se demonstrar como implementar um pequeno jogo em unity, tirando partido de diferentes tipos de funcionalidades, bem como de recursos pré-disponibilizados, com o intuito de introduzir a filosofia de desenvolvimento de jogos em unity.</p><br>
                                            <br>
                                            <p style="text-align:left">As inscrições são gratuítas mas obrigatórias para <a href="#">mariopinto@eseig.ipp.pt</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#text-carousel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#text-carousel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row spacing2" id="thumbnails">
                <h3 id="PlanoEstudos">Projetos</h3>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/Damas.png" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Jogo das damas em Three.js</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/MSDiary.png" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Plataforma de gestão de despesas</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/Crowd.png" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Plataforma de inovação turística</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/localize.jpg" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Plataforma de gestão de equipamentos na ESMAD</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/SmartSquare.png" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Twitter personalizado da Esmad</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/MSDiary.png" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Plataforma de gestão de despesas</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/Crowd.png" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Plataforma de inovação turística</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 spacing4">
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="thumbnails/localize.jpg" style="height:170px; width:240px">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>Plataforma de gestão de equipamentos na ESMAD</h2>
                            <p><a href="#">LINK AQUI</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row spacing2">
                <h3 id="Parceiros">Parceiros</h3>
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4">
                    <a href="http://www.criticalsoftware.com/pt/homepage"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/CriticalSoftware.png"></a>
                </div><a href="http://www.globalmediagroup.pt/">
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/GlobalMedia.png"></div></a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pfrinvest/">
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/pfr.jpg" style="height:100px;width:200px"></div></a> <a href="http://www.planeta-virtual.pt/">
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/PlanetaVirtual.png"></div></a> <a href="https://www.sonae.pt/pt/">
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/Sonae.png"></div></a> <a href="http://www.agros.pt/">
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/Agros.png"></div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 spacing4"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="parceiros/VDC.png" style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="row spacing5">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:5%">
                            <p>Coordenador do curso: Mário Pinto</p>
                            <p>Email: MarioPinto@eseig.ipp.pt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <form action="" class="form-group"></form>
                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" id="" name="" rows="10">Dúvidas gerais acerca do curso...</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3" style="margin-top:12%"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="Pporto.png"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="typed.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="page.js">
            </script> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("a");
    var sentence1 = "System.out.println('TSIW - Um curso em constante inovação')";
    $("#wrapper").typed({
        strings: [sentence1],
        typeSpeed: 30
    });

    $(document).off('keypress');
    var menu = $('.menu2');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('.menu2').addClass('sticky');
            $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            $('.menu2').removeClass('sticky');
            $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }


    }

    document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

**css**

```
body{
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
    font-family: Exo;
}

.menuItem{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:150px;
    font-family:Exo;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:gray;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#menu{
    margin-right:200px;
}


.img-responsive{
    margin:0 auto;
}

#wrapper{
    text-align:center;
}

.centerBlock {
  background-color:#F8F8FF;
}

.spacing{
     margin-top:100px;
}

#Apresentacao{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Exo;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:2.2em;
}

.spacing2{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.aluno{
    margin-top:30px;
}

#competencias{
    padding:15px;
}

#Saidas{
    padding:15px;
}

.backColor {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    padding:0;
}

.foco{
    font-weight:700;
}

iframe{
   display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.spacing4{
    margin-top:20px;
}

#PlanoEstudos{
     text-align:center;
    font-family:Exo;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:2.2em;
}

#Parceiros{
     text-align:center;
    font-family:Exo;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:2.2em;
}

.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}

#Noticias{
     text-align:center;
    font-family:Exo;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:2.2em;
}

.ano{
    display:inline-block;
}


.anos{
padding:0;
}

.ano{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2px;
}

td{
    width:50%;
}



.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
  transform: scale(0,1);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" /></feComponentTransfer></filter></svg>#filter');
  filter: brightness(0.6);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.hovereffect a, hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.65s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.65s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p, .hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.texture{
    background-image: url('texture.jpg');
    padding:0;
}

.spacing5{
    margin-top:150px;
}


.carousel-content {
    color:black;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

#text-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

#noti{
    padding:20px;
}



.logo, .intro, .menu, .content {
    padding:10px;
}
.menu {

    background:#428bca;
    color:#fff;
    height:50px;
    line-height:30px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1; position:relative;

}
.content {
    margin-top:10px;

}
.menu-padding {
    padding-top:40px;
}
.content p {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? The Fiddle seems to work fine in latest Chrome.

Comment: im using chrome, i dont know why the navbar goes behind the content when i scroll down :S

Comment: Post your CSS also

Comment: updated, thanks for your patience